# PATCH 9767 v2 issues, where to download already patched Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

I am trying to revert Patch 9767 but I am receiving a hunk error. Where can I find an original patched version of Magento 1.9.2.3 and 1.9.2.4 to download so I can upload the file in question?

Comment: what is your magento version

Comment: 1.9.2.3 and 1.9.2.4

Comment: in which magento verison you want to revert patch?

Comment: both versions of Magento

Comment: ok do you have a backup of files before you applied patches?

Comment: no, the patch was applied 1 month ago

Comment: in this case you have to revert the patch files to original how they are before you patched manually

Comment: you can find which files are modified at app/etc/applied.patches.list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the original files from the magento download page https://magento.com/tech-resources/download under the release tab.